# Class Design - Object Oriented Programming Question

Tags: class, oop, class-design

This was asked during an interview.

There are different manufacturers of buses. Each bus has got different models and each model has only 2 variants. So different manufacturers have different models with only 2 variants. The interviewer asked me to design a standalone program with just classes. She mentioned that I should not think about databases and I didn't have to code them. For example, it could be a console based program with inputs and outputs.

The manufacturers, models and variants information should be held in memory (hard-coded values were fine for this standalone program). She wanted to observe the classes and my problem solving approach.

**She told me to focus on implementing three APIs or methods for this system.**

The first one was to get information about a particular bus. Input would be manufacturer name, model name and variant name. Given these three values, the information about a particular bus such as its price, model, year, etc should be shown to the client.

The second API would be to compare two buses and the output would be to list the features side by side, probably in a tabular format. Input would be the same as the one for the first API i.e. manufacturer name, model name and variant name for both the buses.

The third one would be to search the buses by price (>= price) and get the list of buses which satisfy the condition.

**She also added that the APIs should be scalable and I should design the solution with this condition on my mind.**

This is how I designed the classes:

```
class Manufacturer {
    private String name;
    private Set<Model> models;
    // some  more properties related to manufacturer
}
```

---

```
class Model {
    private String name;
    private Integer year;
    private Set<Variant> variants;
    // some more properties related to model
}
```

---

```
class Variant {
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    // some more properties related to variant
}
```

---

```
class Bus {
    private String manufacturerName;
    private String modelName;
    private String variantName;
    private Integer year;
    private BigDecimal price;
    // some more additional properties as required by client
}
```

---

```
class BusService {

    // The first method
    public Bus getBusInformation(String manufacturerName, String modelName, String variantName) throws Exception {
        Manufacturer manufacturer = findManufacturer(manufacturerName);
        //if(manufacturer == null) throw a valid exception
        Model model = findModel(manufacturer);
        // if(model == null) throw a valid exception
        Variant variant = findVariant(model);
        // if(variant == null) throw a valid exception
        return createBusInformation(manufacturer, model, variant);
    }

}
```

---

She stressed that there were only 2 variants and there wouldn't be any more variants and it should be scalable. After going through the classes, she said she understood my approach and I didn't have to implement the other APIs/methods. I realized that she wasn't impressed with the way I designed them.

It would be helpful to understand the mistake I made so that I could learn from it.

Comment: This question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @jaco0646 the code here looks too hypothetical for CR and would likely lead to it getting closed as [not on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Perhaps ["Which Site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) would be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpreted your 3 requirements a bit differently (and I may be wrong).  But it sounds like the overall desire is to be able to perform different searches against all Models, correct?

Also, sounds to me that as all Variants are Models.  I suspect different variants would have different options, but nothing to confirm that.  If so, a variant is just a subclass of a particular model.  However, if variants end up having the same set of properties, then variant isn't anything more than an additional descriptor to the model.

Anyway, going on my suspicions, I'd have made Model the center focus, and gone with:

(base class)

```
abstract class Model {
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;
    private String name;
    private String variant;
    private Integer year;
    private BigDecimal price;
    // some more properties related to model
}
```

(manufacturer variants)

```
abstract class AlphaModel {
    AlphaModel() {
        this.manufacturer = new Manufacturer() { name = "Alpha" }
    }

    // some more properties related to this manufacturer
}

abstract class BetaModel {
    BetaModel() {
        this.manufacturer = new Manufacturer() { name = "Beta" }
    }

    // some more properties related to this manufacturer
}
```

(model variants)

```
abstract class AlphaBus : AlphaModel {
    AlphaBus() {
        this.name = "Super Bus";
    }
    // some more properties related to this model
}

abstract class BetaTruck : BetaModel {
    BetaTruck() {
        this.name = "Big Truck";
    }
    // some more properties related to this model
}
```

(actual instances)

```
class AlphaBusX : AlphaBus {
    AlphaBusX() {
        this.variant = "X Edition";
    }
    // some more properties exclusive to this variant
}

class AlphaBusY : AlphaBus {
    AlphaBusY() {
        this.variant = "Y Edition";
    }
    // some more properties exclusive to this variant
}

class BetaTruckF1 : BetaTruck {
    BetaTruckF1() {
        this.variant = "Model F1";
    }
    // some more properties exclusive to this variant
}

class BetaTruckF2 : BetaTruck {
    BetaTruckF2() {
        this.variant = "Model F2";
    }
    // some more properties exclusive to this variant
}
```

Then finally:

```
var data = new Set<Model> {
    new AlphaBusX(),
    new AlphaBusY(),
    new BetaTruckF1(),
    new BetaTruckF2()
}
```

API #1:

```
var result = data.First(x => x.manufacturer.name = <manufactuer> 
                          && x.name = <model>
                          && x.variant = <variant>);
```

API #2:

```
var result1 = API#1(<manufacturer1>, <model1>, <variant1>);
var result2 = API#1(<manufacturer2>, <model2>, <variant2>);
```

API #3:

```
var result = data.Where(x => x.price >= <price>);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say your representation of the Bus class is severely limited, Variant, Model, Manufacturer should be hard links to the classes and not strings. Then a get for the name of each.

E.G from the perspective of Bus bus1 `this.variant.GetName()` or from the outside world. `bus1.GetVariant().name`

By limiting your bus to strings of it's held pieces, you're forced to do a lookup even when inside the bus class, which performs much slower at scale than a simple memory reference.

In terms of your API (while I don't have an example), your one way to get bus info is limited. If the makeup of the bus changes (variant changes, new component classes are introduced), it requires a decent rewrite of that function, and if other functions are written similarly then all of those two.

It would require some thought but a generic approach to this that can dynamically grab the info based on the input makes it easier to add/remove component pieces later on. This will be the are your interviewer was focusing on most in terms of advanced technical&language skills. Implementing generics, delegates, etc. here in the right way can make future upkeep of your API a lot easier. (Sorry I don't have an example)

I wouldn't say your approach here is necessarily bad though, the string member variables are probably the only major issue.